# Cauchy Integral theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z)=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{k^3}{3^k}z^k$, compute 
>   $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)}{z^4}dz$ and $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)sinz}{z^2}dz$.

I do not know how to do these problems. I know it is a closed circle centered at zero and radius $1$ so I must use Cauchy Integral theorem$$
    f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-a}\ dz, $$ but I do not know how to use it explicitly for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be plain that the series has a radius of convergence of 3, so that the only poles within the unit disk are at the origin in either integral.

If this helps, there is a closed-form expression for $f(z)$:

$$f(z) = \frac{\frac{z}{3} \left [\left (\frac{z}{3}\right)^2 + 4 \left (\frac{z}{3}\right ) + 1 \right ]}{\left ( 1-\frac{z}{3} \right )^4}$$

Note the $z$ factor in the numerator.  We may define $g(z) = f(z)/z$ as analytic in the unit disk, and consider

$$\oint_{|z|=1} dz \frac{g(z)}{z^3} = i \pi g''(0)$$

You can work out that

$$g''(x) = \frac{2 \left (1+\frac{x}{3}\right)\left (1+\frac{x}{27}\right)}{\left (1-\frac{x}{3}\right)^6}\implies g''(0)=2$$

Thus, the first integral is $i 2 \pi$.   The second integral is zero because there are no poles at $z=0$ due to the nature of $f$.

Comment: So, if I take the Cauchy integral formula of the closed-form you have, I will then arrive at the correct answer?

Comment: Of course.  I would of course check my work, but I think it's right.  And notice the presence of the $z$ out front, which will cancel one of the $z$'s in the denominator.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try and attempt to solve it now.

Comment: Ron, for the second part the answer is zero. Why is that?

Comment: Because $$\frac{f(z) \sin{z}}{z^2} = \frac{g(z) \sin{z}}{z}$$ is analytic throughout the unit disk, including at $z=0$.

Comment: Ah, thanks. So basically from Cauchy Integral we know that anything analytic in the domain will be zero?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thanks again, that is a very neat, efficent theorem.

Answer (score 3):

This is related to what Alex said and your comment. Using the Cauchy differential formula, we get $$\int_{|z| = 1} \dfrac{f(z)}{z^4} = \frac{2\pi i}{3!}\left(\frac{3!}{2\pi i}\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{f(z)}{z^4} \right) = \frac{2\pi i}{3!} f^{(3)}(0),$$ which you can compute. since you can do term by term differentiation of the series and lots of terms will be zero since you're plugging in zero and $z^k$ is in the terms. For the second one, you can expand $\sin z$ as a power series and then do power series multiplication to get a new series $g(z)$. Then you can apply the same trick as above with $g$ in place of $f$. (Sorry for all the edits!)

Comment: How did you conclude that: 
$$\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{f(z)}{z^4}=f^{(3)}(0)?$$

Comment: Notice what I have is exactly the Cauchy differential formula with $a = 0$ and $n = 3$. Maybe try substituting those into the formula you wrote above and see if you can match what I have.

Comment: Gotcha, I think I got it now. I am going to try an attempt to solve it now.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The [Cauchy Differential Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem) tells you about the coefficients of the Taylor series for a function at a point.

Comment: If I use that formula , I will have: $$
    f^{(n)}(a) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \oint_\gamma \frac{\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{k^3}{3^k}z^k}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\ dz$$ but then what do I have to do in order to arrive at the correct answer?

Comment: @Q.matin That series is the Taylor series for $f$. What is the $n^{\text{th}}$-coefficient of a Taylor series in terms of the function?

Comment: It is $
    \frac{f^{(n)}(b)}{n!} = a_n $ correct?